# Show only days in react date picker

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, days

I want to custumize my DatePicker and only show days cause i want the user to choose one or multiple day from 1 to 31 with ignoring the month and the year

I am using the date picker from `"react-multi-date-picker"`

```js
<DatePicker
  id={"startDate"}
  className="form-control"
  multiple
  format="DD"
/>;
```

Comment: what if the current month doesn't have 31 days? the DatePicker element will only show the current month days if you disable month and year pickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add following props as below

```
 <DatePicker
      id={'startDate'}
      className="form-control"
      multiple
      format="DD"
      buttons={false}
      disableYearPicker
      disableMonthPicker
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dropdown or select instead.

Comment: That would be the alternative solution, but that's not what the OP asked

Answer (score 0):

The prop `button={false}` helped, and I hid the month and the year too.

Finally, it's exactly as I wanted:

```
<DatePicker
            id={"startDate"}
            value={editedDates}
            className="form-control"
            multiple
            format="DD"
            buttons={false}
            disableYearPicker
            disableMonthPicker
            hideMonth
            hideYear
            hideWeekDays
          />
```

[date picker with only days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Qv9.png)